# OR, AND a result from mapcar - lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, logical-operators

My task is to find if a given element is contained in a list (non-linear list). This is what I've written for now, but the return value from this function is a list, which I don't really understand why.

```
(setq E 4)

(defun IsMember (L)
  (cond
    ((equal E L)
      T
    )

    ((atom L)
      NIL
    )

    (T
      (or (mapcar 'IsMember L))
    )
  )
)

(print (IsMember '(1 2 3 (((4) 5) 6))))
```

The returns value is: `(NIL NIL NIL (((T) NIL) NIL))`
But it should really output `T` or `NIL` if `E` is not found in the given list.

Comment: what is OR with one argument for?

Comment: I want to OR the whole list, which contains `T` or `NIL` and as a final result, if at least one `T` in the list, the call returns `T`, otherwise `NIL`, as I learned, mapcar returns a list, but still, I cannot figure out what's wrong here

Comment: but you don't apply or on the elements, but on the list itself. Better see the function SOME.

Comment: `(some 'or (mapcar 'IsMember L))` -> `*** - FUNCALL: OR is a special operator, not a function`

Comment: don't use OR or MAPCAR, use SOME

Comment: Totally off-topic: I didn't "get" Lisp at all until I stopped laying it out the way you do, like in a curly-brackets language. If you start writing (and reading) Lisp like it's usually written, you soon start to see structure where there used to be just a mess of parentheses.

Answer (score 6):

**Your code:**

```
(defun is-member (l e)
  (cond

   ((equal e l)
    t)

   ((atom l)
    nil)

   (t
    (some #'(lambda (a)
              (if (equal t a) t nil))
          (mapcar #'(lambda (b) (is-member b e)) l)))))
```

**Get rid of IF**

You test if something is T and then you return T. You can get rid of that.

```
(defun is-member (l e)
  (cond

   ((equal e l)
    t)

   ((atom l)
    nil)

   (t
    (some #'(lambda (a)
              (equal t a))
          (mapcar #'(lambda (b) (is-member b e)) l)))))
```

**Get rid of EQUAL**

Since the list consists of T and NIL, EQUAL can be replaced, too

```
(defun is-member (l e)
  (cond

   ((equal e l)
    t)

   ((atom l)
    nil)

   (t
    (some #'identity
          (mapcar #'(lambda (b) (is-member b e)) l)))))
```

**Get rid of MAPCAR**

Since MAPCAR returns a list of T and NIL, we can remove that, too.

The result:

```
(defun is-member (list e)
  (cond ((equal list e)  t)
        ((atom list)     nil)
        (t               (some (lambda (b) (is-member b e))
                               list))))
```

**Get rid of COND condition/value pairs**

Since COND is used like an OR, we can replace COND with OR. We don't need to have the condition/value pair anymore:

```
(defun is-member (list e)
  (or (equal list e)
      (and (consp list)
           (some (lambda (b) (is-member b e))
                 list))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution can be rewritten more simply as:

```
(defun is-member (element tree)
  (flet ((recurse (e) (is-member e tree)))
    (or (equal element tree)
        (and (consp tree)
             (some #'recurse tree)))))
```

But you do not even need to use `some`:

```
(defun is-member (element tree)
  (or (equal element tree)
      (and (consp tree)
           (or (is-member element (car tree))
               (is-member element (cdr tree))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, managed to not use OR anymore

```
(defun IsMember (L E)
  (cond
    ((equal E L)
      T
    )

    ((atom L)
      NIL
    )

    (T
      (some #'(lambda (A) (if (equal T A) T NIL)
            (mapcar #'(lambda (B) (IsMember B E)) L))
    )
  )
)
```

Not sure if ethical enought but does the job...

Comment: Try to get rid of MAPCAR, it's easy.

Comment: So if what you're searching for isn't `l` and `l` is a cons then the result would be `tree-member-p` of the `car` **or** the `cdr` :-) Suddenly it will work for `(tree-member-p 4 '(3 . 4))`